# Joomla k2 front-end editing notification

Tags: php, joomla, phpmailer

Am using K2 component on my Joomla website. There is the frond-end editing form that is taken care by itemform.php.

[File on Github](https://github.com/getk2/k2/blob/master/administrator/components/com_k2/views/item/tmpl/default.php)

I have added the following code so that I'm notified whenever a front-end user will add / edit an item:

```
<!-- send email to admin-->
<?php
$to = "admin@domain.com";
$subject = "New Item / Item edited on Website";
$txt = $this->row->title;
$headers = "From: admin@domain.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

A lot of k2 notifications plugins out there works only with older version of k2.
My code works and I'm notified but I will receive the email 2 times. One when front-end editing form is opened and one when it is saved. I would like to place it with the save function so that only when item is saved I will receive a notification. I guess it should be somewhere around line 17 :

```
<?php if($app->isSite()): ?>
<!-- Frontend Item Editing (Modal View) -->
<div id="k2ModalContainer">
    <div id="k2ModalHeader">
        <h2 id="k2ModalLogo"><span><?php echo (JRequest::getInt('cid')) ? JText::_('K2_EDIT_ITEM') : JText::_('K2_ADD_ITEM'); ?></span></h2>
        <table id="k2ModalToolbar" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
            <tr>
                <td id="toolbar-save" class="button">
                    <a href="#" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('save');return false;">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo JText::_('K2_SAVE'); ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td id="toolbar-cancel" class="button">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo JText::_('K2_CLOSE'); ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You need to send your message when your form is submitted; you are sending it when it is loaded, and also when it is submitted. You've not included the code that deals with submission so I can't tell you what you're doing wrong. You second snippet is your form, and a JS call that triggers submission, not PHP that handles it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. Am not sure what to reply. Am a not a PHP coder. The github link contains the complete file. May be a joomla expert should be reply to help here.

Comment: That is only a view file – it determines page layout and form contents. It does not process the form submission. I would expect that to be done in some controller, but it's not clear which one it would be.

Comment: Sending you the link to a test site might help ?

Comment: @Goble if you are interesting in seeking support from "_Joomla experts_", then you may have a better time asking at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange -- a Stack Exchange community dedicated to Joomla support.